# recursion method to count down and up, odds and even

Tags: c++, recursion, computer-science

So the task at hand is to create a recursive method that takes a number, num, and have it print out the squared numbers from one to a specified maximum number. first, display the odd number squares, counting down from the largest, to 1, then back up the even number squares (starting with 2), to the largest even number.

I know how to make the recursion count down fine, but I cant figure out how to make it go back up. Every time I do I get an infinite loop.

```
int squares(int);
int main()          
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    squares(num);

    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    cout << "\nPress only the 'Enter' key to exit program: ";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
int squares(int num)
{
    if (num == 1)
    {
            return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
    {
        num -= 1;
        cout << num * num << " ";
        return squares(num - 2);
    }
    else if (!num % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << num * num << " ";
        return squares(num - 2);
     // edited this because it had an old return i meant to change b4 posting
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `!` has higher operator precedence than `%` so therefore `if (num % 2 == 0)` and `else if (!num % 2 == 0)` do not cover all possibilities. Might not be your problem but it looks odd to me.

Comment: Do you require this to happen in a single function?

Comment: @merlin2011 yes. The version Abhishek posted was close, but it isn't accounting for the number "1". its going through the squares from odd to even, but not showing the # 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function needs to print a value and make a recursive call each time. In the case of odd numbers, you want to output the value first, in the case of even numbers you want to make the recursive call first. So you can do something like this:

```
void squares(int num)
{
  if (num <= 0)
    return;

  if (num % 2 == 0)
  {
    squares(num - 1);
    cout << num * num << endl;
  }

  else
  {
    cout << num * num << endl;
    squares(num - 1);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no need to return anything from the squares function since you are not actually catching its output.

Secondly to get the even number squares, you can output them after the recursion stack unwinds from its call.

```
void squares(int num)
{
    if (num <= 1) // Note the base condition.
    {
            return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
         {
             num -= 1;
             cout << num * num << " ";
             squares(num - 2);
             cout << (num+1) * (num+1) << " "; // now output the even numbered square
         }
         else if (!num % 2 == 0)
         {
             cout << num * num << " ";
             squares(num - 2 + 1);
             cout << (num+1) * (num+1) << " "; // now output the even numbered square
         }
        }
    }
```

http://ideone.com/UE5Whv

Comment: this almost works when you repair the squares(num -2 + 1) line to squares(num - 2). this cycles through the odds then the evens, but not the # 1.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal nvm, i missed the + 1 on your change. my bad

Comment: @jacksonSD You should checkout rainbowgoblin's answer. It is much more elegant.